# Load Html string with image with base64 content in iOS UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, xamarin, uiwebview

I have a HTML string as

```
"<p><span style=\"color &#58;#000000;font-family&#58;&quot;open sans&quot;, arial, sans-serif;text-align&#58;justify;background-color&#58;#ffffff;\">Proin sem urna, aliquet vel placerat quis, semper et mauris. Sed vel nunc lacus. Vestibulum vitae nisl eros. Donec ullamcorper sem nisl, in pellentesque quam tempus vel. Curabitur in felis nec urna placerat finibus. Donec ut nisi eu enim tincidunt luctus. Phasellus eleifend tortor est, nec maximus est aliquet sit amet. Praesent mollis massa id lacinia volutpat. Vestibulum eget odio sit amet enim fringilla pulvinar.</span></p><p><br></p><p><img src=\"data: image / png; base64,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\" alt=\"html_inline_image.png\" title=\"html_inline_image.png\"><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>"
```

This Html string consists of an image tag that has a byte array for image. I am trying to load the html string as follows :-

```
var nsdata = NSData.FromString(mData);
wvNewsDetail.LoadData(nsdata, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", new NSUrl(""));
```

But this simply loads the actual Html string as it is instead of a formatted page.

How can I load this Html string in a WebView?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`text/html; charset=utf-8` would not be a recognized mime type, assign `text/html` as the mime type.

```
wvNewsDetail.LoadData(nsdata, "text/html", "UTF-8", new NSUrl(""));
```

Example:

```
var htmlString = @"
    <p><span style=""color &#58;#000000;font-family&#58;&quot;open sans&quot;, arial, sans-serif;text-align&#58;justify;background-color&#58;#ffffff;"">Proin sem urna, aliquet vel placerat quis, semper et mauris. Sed vel nunc lacus. Vestibulum vitae nisl eros. Donec ullamcorper sem nisl, in pellentesque quam tempus vel. Curabitur in felis nec urna placerat finibus. Donec ut nisi eu enim tincidunt luctus. Phasellus eleifend tortor est, nec maximus est aliquet sit amet. Praesent mollis massa id lacinia volutpat. Vestibulum eget odio sit amet enim fringilla pulvinar.</span></p>
    <p><br></p><p>
    <img src=""data:image/png;base64,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"" alt=""html_inline_image.png"" title=""html_inline_image.png"">
    <br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>

    ";
var uiWebView = new UIWebView(View.Frame);
var nsdata = NSData.FromString(htmlString);
uiWebView.LoadData(nsdata, "text/html", "UTF-8", new NSUrl(""));
Add(uiWebView);
```

[image]